# Why doesn't this regexp matchh?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

```
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QRegExp rx("(.*)[^\\]\\[\\d+\\]$");

    qDebug() << rx.indexIn("AA[45]");
    qDebug() << rx.cap(1);
}
```

I need to write QRegExp for matching the name before '['  symbol if it is not preceded by '\'. In this case it should print "AA" but it prints nothing. After adding adding 2 slashes in [^\\] part it matches only 'A' for `"AA\\[45]"` but for this case I need it to match nothing.

```
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QRegExp rx("(.*)[^\\\\]\\[\\d+\\]$");

    qDebug() << rx.indexIn("AA\[45]");
    qDebug() << rx.cap(1);
}
```

This case shouldn't match anything but it prints "A".

Comment: ...and what does it print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QRegExp rx("(.*[^\\\\])\\[\\d+\\]$");

    qDebug() << rx.indexIn("eeeA\\[45]");
    qDebug() << rx.indexIn("eeeA[45]");
}
```

I get it with your help. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match your letters only if they are followed by a `[` that is not preceeded by a `\`

```
([^\\]*(?!^\\))\[\d+\]$
```